Error al enviar datos a Datatable
Resulta que estoy intentando mostrar datos en una tabla mediante datatable, cree un método de consulta para el cual traigo todos los datos de la table clientes así
Controlador
public function getCustomers()
    {
        $arrData = $this->model->getCustomers();
        $data = array('data' => $arrData, );
        echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        die();
    }

Modelo (Consulto el Id del negocio y luego traigo todos sus clientes)
public function getCustomers()
    {
        //id del usuario
        $this->intUser = $_SESSION['userData']['ID'];
        //consultamos el id_negocio
        $sql = "SELECT id_negocio FROM wp_negocios WHERE id_usuario = '{$this->intUser}' ";
        $respuesta = $this->select($sql);
        $businessId = $respuesta['id_negocio'];
        // consultamos los clientes
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_clientes WHERE id_negocio = '{$businessId}' ";
        $respuesta2 = $this->select_All($sql2);

        return $respuesta2;
    }

La Respuesta es la siguiente:
{"data":[{"id_cliente":1,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"sebastian torres","puntos":"17400","whatsapp":"3269896565","email":"sebasth0709@gmail.com","code_cliente":"SEBITAS","sponsor":"989898","fecha":"2024-06-12 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":2,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"sebastian torres","puntos":"12600","whatsapp":"3269896565","email":"sebasth0709@gmail.com","code_cliente":"SEBAS07","sponsor":"SEBITAS","fecha":"2024-06-12 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":3,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"sebastian torres","puntos":"27000","whatsapp":"3269896565","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"SBAS08","sponsor":"SEBAS07","fecha":"2024-06-12 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":4,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Gorka","puntos":"3000","whatsapp":"573016217578","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"GKC01","sponsor":"SBAS08","fecha":"2024-06-12 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":5,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"sebastian torres","puntos":"0","whatsapp":"3269896565","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"0887487","sponsor":"SBAS08","fecha":"2024-06-14 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":6,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Ivan","puntos":"0","whatsapp":"3129658774","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"IVANLOOT","sponsor":"","fecha":"2024-06-14 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":7,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Ivan","puntos":"0","whatsapp":"3129658774","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"IVANLOOT2","sponsor":"TCT-iGnpqNsq","fecha":"2024-06-14 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":8,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Ivan","puntos":"87000","whatsapp":"3129658774","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"IVANLOOT2w","sponsor":"TCT-iGnpqNsq","fecha":"2024-06-14 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":9,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Adrian","puntos":"0","whatsapp":"573164906336","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"ADRIAN12","sponsor":"IVANLOOT","fecha":"2024-06-17 00:00:00"}]}

Hasta aquí todo bien pero al intentar implementar los datos en la tabla es donde tengo el problema me da el siguiente error:
DataTables warning: table id=myClients - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see https://datatables.net/tn/1

Esta es la tabla:
<table id="myClients" class="table table-striped w-100 display compact stripe">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nombre del Cliente</th>
                <th>Saldo Disponible</th>
                <th>Whatsapp</th>
                <th>Correo</th>
                <th>Código Referidos</th>
                <th>Esponsor</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               
            </tbody>  
          </table>

y así le estoy enviando los datos segun la documentacion del datatable:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var tableCustomers = new DataTable('#myClients', {
language: {
    url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.5/i18n/es-MX.json',
},
ajax: ""+base_url+"oficina/billetera",
 columns: [
    { data: 'nombre_cliente' },
    { data: 'puntos' },
    { data: 'whatsapp' },
    { data: 'email' },
    { data: 'code_cliente' },
    { data: 'sponsor' }
],
responsive: true,
});
});

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionar el error, Agradezco mucho?

¿Es correcto tu base_url? Si hacés la prueba cargando parte de los datos en un archivo json, ¿sí se muestra la tabla correctamente?

gracias por responder he puesto la url directamente y da el mismo error

Y si le pasás el parámetro dataSrc: data, ¿da el mismo error?

@SebastianTorres el JSON parece tener un formato correcto, por lo que podrías proba indicar el Content-type, es decir, haciendo header('Content-Type: application/json'); antes del echo json_encode(... También debería revisar que no haya ninguna otra salida antes y/o después.

Necesitas retornar un array de de rows asi:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var tableCustomers = new DataTable('#myClients', {
language: {
    url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.5/i18n/es-MX.json',
},
data: [{"id_cliente":1,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"sebastian torres","puntos":"17400","whatsapp":"3269896565","email":"sebasth0709@gmail.com","code_cliente":"SEBITAS","sponsor":"989898","fecha":"2024-06-12 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":2,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"sebastian torres","puntos":"12600","whatsapp":"3269896565","email":"sebasth0709@gmail.com","code_cliente":"SEBAS07","sponsor":"SEBITAS","fecha":"2024-06-12 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":3,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"sebastian torres","puntos":"27000","whatsapp":"3269896565","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"SBAS08","sponsor":"SEBAS07","fecha":"2024-06-12 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":4,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Gorka","puntos":"3000","whatsapp":"573016217578","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"GKC01","sponsor":"SBAS08","fecha":"2024-06-12 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":5,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"sebastian torres","puntos":"0","whatsapp":"3269896565","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"0887487","sponsor":"SBAS08","fecha":"2024-06-14 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":6,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Ivan","puntos":"0","whatsapp":"3129658774","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"IVANLOOT","sponsor":"","fecha":"2024-06-14 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":7,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Ivan","puntos":"0","whatsapp":"3129658774","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"IVANLOOT2","sponsor":"TCT-iGnpqNsq","fecha":"2024-06-14 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":8,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Ivan","puntos":"87000","whatsapp":"3129658774","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"IVANLOOT2w","sponsor":"TCT-iGnpqNsq","fecha":"2024-06-14 00:00:00"},{"id_cliente":9,"id_negocio":11,"nombre_cliente":"Adrian","puntos":"0","whatsapp":"573164906336","email":"email@gmail.com","code_cliente":"ADRIAN12","sponsor":"IVANLOOT","fecha":"2024-06-17 00:00:00"}],
 columns: [
    { data: 'nombre_cliente' },
    { data: 'puntos' },
    { data: 'whatsapp' },
    { data: 'email' },
    { data: 'code_cliente' },
    { data: 'sponsor' }
],
responsive: true,
});
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.8/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="myClients" class="table table-striped w-100 display compact stripe">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nombre del Cliente</th>
                <th>Saldo Disponible</th>
                <th>Whatsapp</th>
                <th>Correo</th>
                <th>Código Referidos</th>
                <th>Esponsor</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               
            </tbody>  
          </table>



